# Planet's magnetic properties & Interaction between two magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

If two magnets are placed close together will their interaction be different in different planets for the planet's own magnetic properties?

Even if the planet's affecting the interaction will it very little or very mentionable?

Comment: Depends on the planet. Magnets on Earth automatically orient themselves in the field. The torque on a strong magnet is actually quite strong, I would advise you to try it for yourself with a few Neodymium magnet cubes and a string. Now imagine a planet with a much stronger magnetic field (Jupiter's field is ten times as strong near the edge of its atmosphere and many times stronger than that in its interior). Will those effects change the behavior of your magnets? Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on CuriousOne's comments above, and I  am placing it here solely in case the above comment dissapears.

An example of how the (often quite strong)  interaction between a magnet and external field, occurs can be seen quite easily. By using a compass, you can immediately see that magnetised materials will align with the direction of the planets magnetic field, assuming it is generally homogenous.

The influence of the planet's magnetic field depends on the ratio of the strength of the magnets to the external field produced by the planet.  For example, Jupiter's magnetic field is far greater than that of  Earth.

> The torque on a strong magnet is actually quite strong, I would advise you to try it for yourself with a few Neodymium magnet cubes and a string. Now imagine a planet with a much stronger magnetic field (Jupiter's field is ten times as strong near the edge of its atmosphere and many times stronger than that in its interior). Will those effects change the behavior of your magnets? Yes

Comment: thanks! I'll remove my comment now that it's in answer format.